# Scrapping (básico) con Jsoup no me funciona

Tags: html, netbeans, archivo, jsoup

Soy nuevo en el manejo de la libreria Jsoup, y tengo un problema con un fichero mhtml, con el contenido que se muestra en la imagen, y del que pretendo recuperar el texto de los apartados remarcados. El primero mediante: "doc.select("div[col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12]").select("span[linkSource vcenter h4 text-primary clickable ng-binding]");" donde "doc=Jsoup.parse(sFile,"ISO-8859-15");"
pero no recupera nada.

Lo he intentado con otros métodos de Jsoup (getElementsByTag, getElementsByClass). pero nunca consigo que cargue la información. ¿Cómo se puede hacer?

Alguien me puede ayudar?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]